# Match everything after backslash and before space

Tags: bash, command-line, text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have strings similar to the following:

```
*unknown*\*unknown* (8)
hello\morning (3)
```

I'm trying to match just `morning` or `*unknown\*`.

So far I have tried:

```
[^\\]+$
```

But that matches from backslash to end of line which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `grep`:

```
grep -oP '(?<=\\)[^\\ ]+' file
```

`-o` prints only the matching pattern. The `(?<=...)` is a positive lookahead which matches the backslash `\\`, but it is not part of the matching pattern. The second pattern `[^\\ ]+` follows the backslash and contains all characters, but *no* backslashes and *no* spaces.

---

The output:

```
*unknown*
morning
```